# How to add multiple fields from another table with a foreign key to list_display?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have these two models:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    num_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and

```py
class PostDetails(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=512)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=2, default="en")  # could be "en", "jp", "fr", etc... 
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="post", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["post", "language"]
```

I want to display the info from the `PostDetails` in the `Post`'s `list_display`. In the `admin.py` file I have the following:

```py
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [...]
    inlines = [...]


    list_display = ["user", "en_title", "fr_title", "jp_title", "pup_date", "num_views"]  # each one needs to be in its own column 


    def en_title(self, obj):
        return obj.post.get(post=obj.id, language="en")


    def fr_title(self, obj):
        return obj.post.get(post=obj.id, language="fr")


    def jp_title(self, obj):
        return obj.post.get(post=obj.id, language="fr")
```

Although this gives me the `list_display` I want, it adds a query for each column that I add from the `PostDetails` model.

I thought about using `prefetch_related` and `select_related`, but I couldn't find a way to share the query set between functions.

Is there anyway I could fetch all the data I need from the post_details table with a single query? Or at least as minimum queries as possible.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: you can use list_display as choices in post_details

Answer (score 1):

You can display post details admin as below and get the fields from your posts

```
class PostDetailsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'get_title')

    def get_title(self, obj):
        return obj.post.pub_date
```

Comment: You mean the other way around. I thought about it, but I need the change/edit link to point to the parent form, as the children forms are inline with the parent form to add and update all forms with parent form in one place

Comment: You can get the child field set by calling postdetails_set.all() method.